# Google-Visualization Plugin Grails: How to set hAxis max value and color formatting

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm using the [google-visualization](http://grails.org/plugin/google-visualization) in grails and would like to configure two things:

1) How can I set the maximum value along the horizontal axis?
2) How can I change the bar column if it falls below a certain value?

Here's what I have:

```
<td>
<div id="${mach.divtag}" style="display:block;">    
<gvisualization:columnCoreChart elementId="${mach.divtag}" width="${150}"
     height="${120}" columns="${mac.columns}" data="${mach.datapoints}"
     title="${mach.name}" />
</div>
```

Here's a snapshot of what I'm hoping to change in the charts.

[image]

Thanks. I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://grails.org/plugin/google-visualization):

> Q: How do I set values for a visualization object data type like the
>   column core chart's "hAxis"?
>
> A: You can easily do this by using an Expando or a custom bean class.
>   "textColor", "title" and "titleColor" are fields of this object.

From the [examples of the plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/grails-google-visualization/blob/master/grails-app/views/index.gsp)

```
<gvisualization:columnCoreChart elementId="columnchart" title="Company Performance" width="${400}" height="${240}" hAxis="${new Expando(title: 'Year', titleColor: 'red')}" columns="${companyPerformanceColumns}" data="${companyPerformanceData}" />
```

Therefore, for **a)**, use an Expando and set the hAxis.maxValue, per the [Google API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes.html#05182010)

```
hAxis="${new Expando(maxValue:100)}"
```

for **b)**, you will probably have to do this yourself in Javascript using the Google API to get the bars using a [combination of getSelection() for all available bars and setSelection() with some kind of color modifier after you've interrogated its value](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart.html#Configuration_Options). Hopefully you can handle it from here, otherwise seek consulting help.